# Stuttering HTML 5 video while looping

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

The video loops seamlessly when played using a Media Player. It's not the video file that is stuttering. I cant for the life of me, find a solution to this.

I've setup a jsfiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Dillybob/to30r7rv/4/

*(Please give it a few seconds to load, I'm using a free hosting account)*

---

```
 <video id="video1" width="1280" height="973" autoplay="true" loop="true">
   <source src="http://dillybob.byethost14.com/background.webm" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

**The problem:**

The video is roughly 17 seconds long. Wait until **16** seconds pass, and stare at the video, you will notice a tiny 100-300 ms 'freeze' before it begins the next loop.

Edit: I tested this on `Firefox` and it does the same thing, but the freeze isn't as long. I also tested   a very low quality `.webm` version of my video (around 2MB in size) and the freeze seemed even shorter... but you can still notice it.  I am thinking this is a video filesize issue w/ looping maybe?

Comment: The test file is encoded using VP9 and I am having troubles watching it. My versions of VLC and avplay don't support it. This is just a wild guess but have you tried converting it to h264 or VP8?

Comment: @SvetlinMladenov Yeah, I have tried H264 mp4's as well. Here is a vp8 encoded one: https://jsfiddle.net/Dillybob/to30r7rv/5/   The freeze is still there, and that one works in VLC so u can see the seamless.

Answer (score -1):

Your Working Code is Here :

```
<video id="video1" width="1280" height="973" controls autoplay loop>
<source src="http://dillybob.byethost14.com/background.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Your Mistakes were :

1. Video type was wrong
2. loop is boolean itself so it should be defined explicitly only in XHTML because there attribute minimization is forbidden

Cheers :)